# Ubuntu 21.10: Unable to Boot - Unable to mount root FS on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount, 20.10

I recently updated to Ubuntu 21.10 from 21.04 and after rebooting, I get the following error:
[image: Error message]

I am able to boot using am older kernel version and from searching, I have running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo update-initramfs -u` including for the problematic Kernel version but I am still unable to boot using the latest kernel.

Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Comment: What is the exact update-initramfs command that you used? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: Do you tried `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Yes, I did but it did not work.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks but I ended up getting it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue by installing the package `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` through the command line with the command `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04` in a terminal window.

It seems like there were some problems which occurred during the update and some packages were missing.